# Xubuntu 20.04 does not boot properly, has many errors on boot, and will not start the desktop environment. How can I fix this?

Tags: boot, 20.04, xubuntu

Here is all the information I have on what is going on:

System Information:

- Lenovo ThinkPad T420
- XUbuntu 20.04
- Kingston 240GB A400 SATA 3 2.5" Internal SSD SA400S37/240G
- 16GB RAM

Kernels Installed:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-41-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-110-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-110-generic (recovery mode)

When I reboot my machine, I see many errors like this:

```
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[        ] EXT4-fs (sda5): Unrecognized mount option "errors=remount -rw" or missing value
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[        ] EXT4-fs (sda5): Unrecognized mount option "errors=remount -rw" or missing value
[FAILED] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
See 'systemctl status systemd-remount-fs.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[        ] EXT4-fs (sda5): Unrecognized mount option "errors=remount -rw" or missing value
[FAILED] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[  OK  ] Found device KINGSTON_SA400S37240G 1.A
         Activating swap /swapfile...
         Starting File System Check.../dev/disk/by-uuid/A8E3-58E9...
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[  OK  ] Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
```

When I log in - command line only as the GUI does not start - I see this:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 31: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system
mktemp: failed to create file via template '/var/lib/update-notifier/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX': Read-only file system
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol exited with return code 1
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 38: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
```

and

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.3.4
/dev/sda5: clean, 531702/14622720 files, 19917791/58476032 blocks
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing changes.
/dev/sda1: 0 files, 1/130812 clusters
Job for systemd-remount-fs.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-remount-fs.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the output from some commands:

`# lsblk`

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM      SIZE   R0    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0    223.6G    0    disk
├─sda1      8:1    0      512M    0    part    /boot/efi
├─sda2      8:2    0        1K    0    part
└─sda5      8:5    0    223.1G    0    part    /
sr0        11:0    1     1024M    0    rom
```

`# blkid`

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="ea1aea58-db6b-419f-bf3d-0919bb3c1443" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fec6badc-05"
/dev/sda1: UUID="A8E3-58E9" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="fec6badc-01"
```

`# cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if the disks are added and removed. See fstab (5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ea1aea58-db6b-419f-bf3d-0919bb3c1443 /    -rw    0    1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A8E3-58E9    /boot/efi    vfat    umask=0077    0    1
/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0
```

Using Xubuntu Install Disk

`# fdisk -l`

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 468860927 467808258 223.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 468860927 467808256 223.1G 83 Linux
```

I have used an Xubuntu install disk to boot my machine and used `gparted` on my disk, and this is what I see:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Crazy error and well- asked question with all the needed info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In /etc/fstab  in your installation

change

```
UUID=ea1aea58-db6b-419f-bf3d-0919bb3c1443 /    -rw   0    1
```

to

```
UUID=ea1aea58-db6b-419f-bf3d-0919bb3c1443 /    ext4  defaults    0    1
```

Comment: That did it ... THANK YOU! How does something like this even happen? I mean, I was using it fine until I rebooted yesterday. There were some system updates, but this has never happened before with updates.

Comment: How did you know that? More specifically: What's wrong with `-rw   0    1`? And: How on earth did it get on the OP's disk if it doesn't work?

Comment: read the lsblk and fstab it shows the system is starting but with errors. so he/she had acces to it.   the third field in fstab is for the filesystem (ext4 or vfat or ntfs for example) the fourth field is for mount options but it has to be formated (user,auto,exec ) like this comma separated.